# Can nginx handle duplicate X-Forwarded-For headers?

Tags: php, nginx

When user using proxy (Google data saver etc), the browser adds X-Forwarded-For for clients' real ip address to server. Our load balancer passes all headers + the clients' ip address as X-Forwarded-For header to nginx server. The example request headers:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Host: *.*.*.*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.6
Save-Data: on
Scheme: http
Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.5
Connection: Keep-alive
```

Is there any way to pass both of the X-Forwarded-For headers to php, respectively?

Comment: iirc the second one overwrites the first one. Your load balancer should do `X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5`

Comment: It cannot, it is managed service, so i cannot change anything

Comment: What do you get currently in your PHP script?

Comment: nginx surely can handle this, but it is unclear what kind of setup you're talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

- nginx: `fastcgi_param HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR $http_x_forwarded_for`
- php: `$_SERVER['HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`

### Explanation

You can access all http headers with [the `$http_<header_name>` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_). When using this variable, nginx will even do header merging for you so

```
CustomHeader: foo
CustomHeader: bar
```

Gets translated to the value:

```
foo, bar
```

Thus, all you need to do is pass this variable to php [with `fastcgi_param`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param)

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR $http_x_forwarded_for
```

### Proof of concept:

**in your nginx server block:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR $http_x_forwarded_for;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
die($_SERVER['HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
```

**And finally see what happens with curl:**

```
curl -v -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1' -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8' http://localhost/test.php
```

**Gives the following response:**

```
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
> X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 01 Nov 2017 09:07:51 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8
```

Boom! There you go, you have access to all `X-FORWARDED-FOR` headers, as a comma-delimited string in `$_SERVER['HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`

Of course, you can use whatever name you want and not just `HTTP_MERGED_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know nginx merged headers did you find it somewhere (where?) or just found out yourself?

Comment: Well, It is not officially documented as far as I know, but the behaviour is supported by the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2), and [it is known the same behaviour exists for add_header](https://serverfault.com/q/350330/112431), furthermore, it is hinted this is the favoured behavor in the [bug tracker](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1316) and in the [wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/#how-to-use-it-in-nginx) (*This is in contrast to $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for, which does correctly join multiple incoming headers.*).

Comment: So, yeah, I guess I just found it out by myself somewhere along the road. Though, I had a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the original client address of the connecting ELB in the variable `$realip_remote_addr`, but be aware that this variable was only added in nginx 1.9.7, so you'll need to be running a very recent version of nginx.

For more info. [ngx_http_realip_module variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#variables)

For example, with this config:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.2.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

And an `X-Forwarded-For` header resulting in:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 123.123.123.123, 192.168.2.1, 127.0.0.1
```

By default, nginx will pick up the leftmost IP `123.123.123.123` as the client's IP address apart from trusted proxies.

But `$realip_remote_addr` keeps the original client address

Comment: Could you confirm it merges `real_ip_header` if there are many?

Comment: @MatTheCat Can't confirm.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for needs to be handled at web server level. So I created two servers one using apache and one using nginx for this. The test command

```
curl -H "X: Y" -H "X: Z"  http://localhost:8088/router.php | jq
```

**Apache**

When executed using apache the output is below

```
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "Host": "localhost:8088",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "X": "Y, Z"
  }
}
```

As you can see we passed two headers to apache and apache combined them using `,`. If we change our first header to already contain `,` it would still work fine

```
$ curl -H "X: Y, A" -H "X: Z"  http://localhost:8088/router.php | jq
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "Host": "localhost:8088",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "X": "Y, A, Z"
  }
}
```

**Nginx**

Now same request on nginx yields

```
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "X": "Z",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0",
    "Host": "localhost"
  }
}
```

Now it is not that Nginx is not sending those headers to PHP-FPM, it does send them as it is. PHP-FPM doesn't merge these duplicate headers into one. So in the script you only get the latest header.

**Edit-1: Merge using fastcgi_param**

Thanks to @AronCederholm for pointing out that merging does work by specifying FASTCGI_PARAM

I originally had tested the same approach but it had resulted in blank headers. I had tried adding

```
fastcgi_param X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarder_for;
```

Just now after reading his message I realized that I had a typo in my config. It should have been

```
fastcgi_param X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
```

And after this change the header does work fine. It won't come in getallheaders() though. It would be available through `$_SERVER[]` as shown in below response

```
$ curl -v -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1' -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8' http://localhost/router.php | jq
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "X-Forwarded-For": "8.8.8.8",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0",
    "Host": "localhost"
  },
  "SERVER": {
    "USER": "vagrant",
    "HOME": "/home/vagrant",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR": "8.8.8.8",
    "HTTP_ACCEPT": "*/*",
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT": "curl/7.47.0",
    "HTTP_HOST": "localhost",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8",
```

**Original Answer**

Unfortunately I found no settings or plugins for Nginx or PHP-FPM which allows you to merge the duplicate headers into one. And you cannot handle this situation at PHP level, because you will never be able to see the raw headers.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Put apache in front of Nginx. Make nginx listen on a unix socket and use apache to reverse proxy the request to nginx
2. Replace Nginx by Apache
3. Create a Nginx plugin to merge headers. Below two projects should give you a head start

https://github.com/giom/nginx_accept_language_module

https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

Comment: Actually, nginx does header merging for you. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051518/150926) on how to trigger this.

Comment: @AronCederholm, Thanks for pointing out. After digging again I realized where I went wrong in my research. I had typo while testing the same solution, and I thought nginx was not handling the situation instead of double checking my config

Answer (score 0):

The headers for X-Forwarded-For should be appended to by each proxy inline of your request.  You should not be getting two headers.   Because the values are appended to by design, anyone can add ip's to that list, so do not use it for security checks.  If you need to check an ip for security, set the X-Real-IP header on your web server, overwriting any passed in value.